# Building another dataframe using minimun values of the columns using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a probleme where I have a pandas DataFrame with name df_x where my index is the name of persons and my columns are the name of products. The values are the distance between these persons to the products
I want to build another table containing the columns of df_x and as values the name of the person that have the minimun distance to this product.

Is there a simple way to do this using pandas or np? Do I need to use for loop?

Example:

```
(index)  Banana  Apple
Mike     7       2
Kevin    2       4
James    3       6
```

so the final table should be

```
(index)  Banana  Apple
Name     Kevin   Mike
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, [`DataFrame.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html)

```
df_x.idxmax().to_frame('Name').T
```

---

**Output**

```
     Banana  Apple
Name   Mike  James
```